# Trying to change some data types to read a different output other than numbers

Tags: java, class, object, overloading

I am thinking I need to do some type casting to get the fan to output `toString`,

to output strings for my speed instead of 1, 2, and 3. I am not sure where I can makes those changes, either being sent in the test class or moving to private in the fan class. I have tried to add some calls in the toString but I am getting the hex decimal result. Some different ways to come around this would be really helpful.

```
public class Fan { 
    public final int SLOW = 1; 
    public final int MEDIUM = 2; 
    public final int FAST = 3; 

    private int speed; // = SLOW; 
    private boolean on; // on = false; 
    private double radius; // radius = 5; 
    private String color; // = "white"; 



    public int getSpeed ( ) {return speed; } 

    public void setSpeed ( int speed ) { this.speed = speed; } 

    public boolean isOn ( ) {return on; } 

    public void setOn ( boolean on) {this.on = on; } 

    public double getRadius ( ) {return radius; } 

    public void setRadius ( double radius ) { this.radius = radius; } 

    public String getColor ( ) { return color; } 

    public void setColor ( String color ) { this.color = color; } 

    public Fan ( ) { 
        System.out.println("Default constructor called");
    } 
    // default constructor

    public Fan ( int speed, boolean on, double radius, String color ) { 
       this.speed = speed;
       this.on = on;
       this.radius = radius;
       this.color = color;
       System.out.println("Overloaded constructor called");
    } 
    //overloaded constructor

    public String toString () { 
       String x = "speed is " + speed + ", is the fan turned on? " + on + ",the       radius "
        + "of the blades are " + radius + ", and the color of the fan is "   +      color;
       return x;
    } 

}

public class FanTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fan f1 = new Fan( 3,  true, 10, "Yellow" )  ;
        Fan f2 = new Fan();
        Fan f4 = new Fan();
        f1.equals(f4) ;
        Fan f3 = f1;
        int slow = 1;
        int medium = 2;
        int fast = 3;

            System.out.println(f1);
            System.out.println(f2);
            System.out.println(f3);

        if (f1.equals(f3)) {
          System.out.println("Obejects r3 and r1 are the same\n");
        } else { 
          System.out.println("Objects r3 and r1 are different");
        }

        while (f1.equals(f4)) 
            f4.setOn(false);
            f4.setSpeed(2);
            f4.setColor("green");
            f4.setRadius(8);
            System.out.println(f4);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, in the default constructor no variables are set. This means that any Fan object created with the default constructor is in an invalid state (e.g. `speed` is `0` by default). I suggest you to uncomment line 9-12:

```java
private int speed = SLOW;
private boolean on = false;
private double radius = 5;
private String color = "white";
```

You said you wanted to "output strings for my speed instead of 1, 2, and 3". This can easily be achieved using `if..else` or `switch`.

```
if (speed == 1) {
    str = str + " slow ";
} else if (speed == 2) {
    str = str + " medium ";
} else if (speed == 3) {
    str = str + " fast ";
}
```

Using switch:

```java
switch (speed) {
    case 1:
        str = str + " slow ";
        break;
    case 2:
        str = str + " medium ";
        break;
    case 3:
        str = str + " fast ";
        break;
}
```

About `f1.equals(f4)`: These are different objects, so it is never `true`.

About `equals`: `equals` is a method defined in the class `Object`, so it can be used on any object. But unless you override it, it checks for **identity**, witch means that

```
a.equals(b)
```

always returns the same as

```
a == b
```